# How to get key and value pairs from converted JSON file

Tags: json, powershell, performance, filtering

I converted in PowerShell a JSON file into a variable.

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Path "$LogFile" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Sample (Object):

```
Id                  : Directory_825efe20-2c90-4b90-885f-589a38360cb9
Category            : ApplicationManagement
CorrelationId       : 825efe20-2c90-4b90-885f-589a38360cb9
Result              : success
ResultReason        : 
ActivityDisplayName : Update service principal
ActivityDateTime    : 20.09.2023 08:00:05
LoggedByService     : Core Directory
OperationType       : Update
InitiatedBy         : @{User=; App=}
TargetResources     : {@{Id=14fa3ae9-6dc9-4267-a681-368aa59ffbc8; DisplayName=ODS API; Type=ServicePrincipal; UserPrincipalName=; GroupType=; ModifiedProperties=System.Object[]}}
AdditionalDetails   : {@{Key=User-Agent; Value=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.62}, @{Key=AppId; Value=563e60f7-4012-491a-b10b-493afb3f2154}}
```

What is the best way (regarding performance) to extract a specific key/value pair for example the "User-Agent" from the AdditionalDetails property?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What I have so far...but the User-Agent is not always exisitng: 
($Data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AdditionalDetails | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'User-Agent'}).Value

Comment: Use [Member-Access Enumeratiion](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration). As an aside, you better add the source `json` file to your question so that it can be answered more specific.

Comment: Can you add your original json document to your post for reference?

Comment: I've added sample JSON to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: See the bottom section for *sample JSON* that the solutions can be tested with.</sup>

A **concise** solution that **performs reasonably well**, using the [intrinsic `.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```bash
$objectOfInterest = 
  $JSON.AdditionalDetails.Where({ $_.Key -eq 'User-Agent' }, 'First')[0]
```

Note the need for `[0]`, due to `.Where()` always returning a *collection* of results (even though by definition there is at most *one* in this case).

---

The following is likely **faster**, but **more verbose** and less conceptually direct, using a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement*:

```bash
$objectOfInterest = 
  foreach ($obj in $JSON.AdditionalDetails) { 
    if ($obj.Key -eq 'User-Agent') { $obj; break }
  }
```

---

The **slowest** - but arguably most **PowerShell-idiomatic** - option is to use the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet*:

```bash
$objectOfInterest = 
  $JSON.AdditionalDetails | Where-Object Key -eq User-Agent
```

<sup>Note the use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), i.e. `Key -eq User-Agent` in lieu of `{ $_.Key -eq 'User-Agent' }`</sup>

Note that this will invariably process *all* input objects, because `Where-Object` offers *no* way to stop filtering once a match has been found. To do so, additional work would be required.

- This surprising omission - especially given that `Where-Object`'s expression-mode counterpart, `.Where()` *does* have this feature, as shown above (`'First'`) - is the subject of [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834).

As for **why this is slowest**:

- The PowerShell [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) (`|`), due to its object-by-object handoff between the commands involved, invariably introduces overhead.

  - However, note that **the pipeline is an elegant, core feature of PowerShell** that is generally worth taking advantage of, and **only worth avoiding *if performance requires it***.
- This overhead alone is not dramatic, but exacerbated by the ***currently inefficient implementation* of the `Where-Object` cmdlet** (as well as **`ForEach-Object`**), as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x

  - See [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982) for a discussion and suggested improvements.
- Finally, as noted, the fact that `Where-Object` (and `ForEach-Object`) invariably processes *all* input, with no ability to (gracefully) *stop* the pipeline once a match has been found, introduces overhead.

  - Introducing a `-First` switch, as discussed in the aforementioned [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834), would solve that specific problem.
  - However, there's also a need for a *general* mechanism to gracefully stop a pipeline from user code, as discussed in [GitHub issue #3821](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3821).

---

**Sample JSON** that the solutions above can be tested with (the basic structure matches the one implied by the *for-display* representation of the parsed-from-JSON object shown in your question):

```bash
# Note: Better to call this variable $fromJSON, for instance.
$JSON = @'
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "AdditionalDetails": [
    {
      "Key": "AppId",
      "Value": "563e60f7-4012-491a-b10b-493afb3f2154"
    },
    {
      "Key": "User-Agent",
      "Value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.62"
    }
  ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```